# What is white meat and dark meat in Canada KFC?

Tags: chicken, meat, poultry

According to US KFC, a chicken is cut into 2 breasts, 2 wings, 2 thighs and 2 drumsticks. White meat is breasts and wings, dark meat is thighs and drumsticks. But on KFC Canada's website, the options confuse me. Do they have different cuts or a different meaning?

[image]

From [kfc.ca/different-pieces](https://www.kfc.ca/different-pieces)

[image]

Comment: Does https://www.kfc.ca/different-pieces help you?

Comment: @KateGregory It really helps,  I didn't use the right keywords when searching.

Comment: Wings aren't white meat.  "White meat with wings" is likely a breast piece + wings, as opposed to "breast only".  (and based on the image tthat Kate found, it's possible that "breast only" is 3/4, while "white meat" is 3/4/5/6, but I that's more a guess than anything else)

Comment: @KateGregory I just get an Access Denied error when I access that link.

Comment: Me too. Might be geofenced.

Comment: @nick012000  I added the screenshot of the page to the question

Comment: As an unrelated note... How on earth can you take the same product, cut it up into more pieces and get the same amount of product in an N piece bucket?

Comment: @talon8 you can't, if you think on a weight by weight ratio. Basically they're making the pieces relatively smaller (if you look at the division before and after, 6 and 8 became 7, 8, 10 and 11; and 5 became 5 and 6), so that's a sneaky way to disguise an increase in price. Another evidence that points to that is that "breast only" is significantly more expensive than the other options

Comment: @Juliana, oh I caught that. I am completely amazed at how un-sneaky it is. "Don't worry, we are just giving you less." I am even more flabbergasted that if it works on anybody.

Comment: @talon8 It works very well, actually - the average consumer is more sensitive to price increase than quantity decrease, so "shrinkflation" is a common price increase tactic. I found this article that's pretty comprehensive on the basics https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2021/06/01/package-sizes-shrink-inflation/

Comment: Akk! We're eating four-breasted chickens!!

Comment: @talon8 the ‘different pieces’ graphic also contains text to the effect that *sone* of their suppliers now grow larger chickens so *some* will be cut differently. I’m not saying whether it’s a shrinkflation thing or not, but there is a rationale and they don’t say they are changing all of their butchery.

Answer (score 4):

So, since nobody answered it yet, this is a classic case of ["shrinkflation"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2021/06/01/package-sizes-shrink-inflation/), which is companies disguising increase in price by reducing serving / package size. Which, coupled with the already expected [difference in portion sizes](https://www.insider.com/every-difference-between-us-uk-fast-food-portion-sizes-2021-2) between countries, may lead to confusion if you're used only to your country standard.

The 9-cut diagram on the left represents the original 9-piece cut scheme from KFC, with:

- 2 wings (1 and 2)
- 2 breasts (3 and 4)
- 1 keel (5)
- 2 thighs (6 and 8)
- 2 drumsticks (7 and 9).

Of those cuts, only the breasts and the keel are considered white meat.

KFC then proceeded to "shrinkflate" by changing the cut scheme to the one on the right, with 12-pieces by splitting the larger pieces in 2, so you have now:

- 2 wings (1 and 2)
- 2 breasts (3 and 4)
- 2 keels (5 and 6)
- 4 thighs (7, 8, 10 and 11)
- 2 drumsticks (9 and 12)

The classification of white x dark meat doesn't change, so you'll have 2 breasts and 2 keels as white meat and all the remaining parts as dark meat

Now, let's talk about one important concept in food pricing that's called "non-edible portion". Chicken has bones, which are considered non-edible, and those bones are not uniformly distributed across the chicken. If you take a good look at the different chicken pieces you'll see that the white meat (breasts and keels) has relatively less bones, with the breast having more meat than the keel. So, you get more meat per piece of chicken.

Of course, KFC has accounted for that when designing the menu, so that's why you're going to pay the normal price for the standard dark meat pieces and pay extra for the following options, as you're effectively getting more chicken:

- White meat with wings = replace 1 dark meat (expected to be a thigh or drumstick) piece with 1 white meat (breasts or keel), pay +1,50
- White meat only = replace both pieces of dark meat with white meat, pay +2,50
- Breast only = receive only the chicken parts with more meat per piece, pay +4,00

Comment: You can eat chicken bones if you really want to. Don't know if you can really call it inedible.